# iTunesConnect acces to download stats for my client

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I've developed an app for a client and would like to give him an access to my iTunesConnect in order to access to the download stat for his application.

The problem is that if I create a new user and set permission to only see reports, he will be able to get all stats...

And I don't want to get stats manually each day.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is open an account with www.appfigures.com, it imports and parses your reports then displays them in interactive graphs and sends email reports.

You can then set up an email report for just that app to send to just your client's email, and he'll get a full report that includes sales, downloads, and updates (total + by country) as well as an alert if the app is ranked in the top 100 anywhere in the world. Reports can be either daily or weekly.

And appfigures.com is currently (free while in beta)